# Archiving/Zipping Software

Tags: software, zip

What compression application would allow you to also encrypt a file?

Comment: That's off-topic there.

Comment: Please clarify what "best" means to you here.

Comment: I think editing the question to remove the subject aspects could still make it useful. Something like "What compression application would allow you to..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only free (albeit not open source) Mac OS GUI compression utility I'm aware of is [B1](http://b1.org). It does support password protecting archives, although not encrypting them.

Two commercial applications that do support encrypted archives are:

- [Winzip](http://www.winzip.com/mac/en/index.htm)
- [StuffIt](http://my.smithmicro.com/stuffit-deluxe-mac.html)

That said, if you're happy using the command line, the [zip](http://info-zip.org) utility provided with Mac OS can do password-based encryption (look at the `-P` option).

Comment: Great thanks! I will check out stuff it, and the command line option.

Comment: I see the zip command and also tar command. How can you encrypt using tar?

Comment: `tar` doesn't support password protection/encryption out of the box. You'd need to use additional software to provide that functionality - for example, GnuPG. You create the tar file and then use GnuPG to encrypt - this can be done for any file really, including ZIP files.